# Как переместить поле из блока Пользователь в блок Доставка в форме оформления заказа?

Tags: битрикс

Вопрос по sale.order.ajax, как можно перенести в форме оформления заказа поле **Адрес доставки** из блока **Пользователь** в блок **Доставка**?
http://joxi.ru/a2X9ZGpu1gwQ1A

Как я понимаю настройкой Битрикс эту проблему не решить. Необходимо кастомизировать компонент sale.order.ajax

В компоненте sale.order.ajax основная логика реализована в JS файле order_ajax.js
Делал ли кто то перенос полей из одного блока в другой используя order_ajax.js?

Comment: не больно то он редактируется. попробуйте воспользоваться [этой статьёй](https://verstaem.com/lessons/making-sale-order-ajax-d7/):

Comment: Все проще чем вам кажется. Перейдите в "Магазин"-"Настройка магазина" и найдите пункты "Свойства заказа" и "Группы заказа". И там настривайте свойства так как вам нужно, шаблон компонента тянет информацию оттуда. Если вы перенесете что-то из одной группы в другую компонент это подхватит и не надо никуда лезть и менять.

Comment: настроятельно рекомендую обратить внимание на курс ["Администратор.Бизнес"](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42) если бы вы его открыли, то не задавали бы глупого вопроса.